# URL strings - folder depth

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have folder paths in column A which has a folder path.

First example, \\SERVERNAME\FILESHARE\1_Folder\2_Folder\3_Folder\

Second example, \\SERVERNAME\FILESHARE\1_Folder\2_Folder\

I would like to extract the depth of each final folder (after the fileshare as this will always be the same) into a new column(s).

So in above first example it would show a depth of 3.

In second example it would show a depth of 2.

How is this achieved?

Thanks

Comment: Do all paths end with a backslash?

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
 =LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))-4
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Comment: @donnashim  yes .................... in cell **B2** enter  =LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"\",""))-4

Comment: If the path does not always end with a \ or start with 2, calculate the subtraction number as needed. `-3-if(right(trim(b1),1)="\"),1,0)`